# What's the meaning of the $-\equiv-$-like bond symbol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, lewis-structure

In the following image, $\mathrm{CH}_2$ is connected to benzene rings with a $-\equiv-$ like symbol. What's the meaning of this symbol?

[image: Organic chemistry powered double-barrier resonant tunneling diode]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a triple bond between two $\ce{C}$ atoms, i.e. $\ce{-C#C -}$. It is drawn that way because the carbon atoms in a triple bond are $\mathrm{sp}$-hybridised and thus exhibit a linear arrangement.

Comment: If this is a triple bond, then why [here](http://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/US8008854B2/US08008854-20110830-C00010.png) the benzene rings are with a single bond?

Comment: @Sparkler Sorry, I don't understand your question. Benzene rings can only directly be linked by a single bond, because you can't have a carbon atom with 5 bonds (notwithstanding very rare exceptions). If you link them via a carbon chain then this chain can contain single, double or triple bonds.